# Retrofit multiple image upload issue using rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a POST api which takes 1 image(of Multipart form) as parameter(key is "document1"). I'm using Retrofit v2.3.0 with Rxjava(rxandroid) v2.0.1 dependencies.

What I wanna achieve is really simple: **Upload four images and close current activity**; that being said, I have to call the api **4** times as the backend api is only taking **1** image at a time.

So far what I've done is getting the `Uri`s of these four images(be it from camera or gallery), converting these images to Multipart(these parts work, phew!).

Now, my api call implementation is like below:

```
 @Multipart
 @POST("upload_image.php")
 Observable<ImageUploadResponse> uploadProblemImages(@Part MultipartBody.Part part);
```

I'm calling the above method in my activity once, I check that I have 4 images selected: 
`uris` containing 4 different uris,

`prepareFilePart()` will convert my images to Multipart

 and `CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();` created in `onCreate()`

```
 for (Uri uri : uris)
        mCompositeDisposable.add(getApiInterface___().uploadProblemImages(prepareFilePart("document1", uri)).
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(this::handleResponse, this::handleError));
```

`handleResponse` is the method where I increment an integer `count` each time this method gets called and if it's equal to **4**, I *finish* the current activity.

```
private void handleResponse(ImageUploadResponse imageUploadResponses) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "success" + imageUploadResponses.getMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("hit", imageUploadResponses.getMsg());
    count++;
    Log.e("count", String.valueOf(count));// logging the success count
    if (count == 4) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Problem has been added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(STR_KEY_IDENTIFIER, mIdentifier);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        count = 0;
        finish();
    }
}
```

But for some reasons, I see in the logcat the count and notice that the activity gets finished even before the completion of uploading with count value being 2 or 1 or 3 each time in logcat. But, the strange thing is I'm getting all 4 images in the database.

> So, what I really wanna do is get to know that I have uploaded 4 images successfully and, only then, finish the current activity. I'm new to RxJava; if anyone knows something about this being helpful to my problem, please guide. Thanks.

Comment: Is your `count` variable `synchronized`?

Comment: No, it's not. I'm afraid that's the problem. I'll *modify its specifier* and let you know. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Charlie Neikirk ~Or would it be better if I just declare `handleResponse()` as **synchronized** ?

Comment: @Tamaribenneharibhailaijay please change your name

Comment: @Nilu ~Sorry for that, my silly Indian roommate likes to mess around.

Answer (score 0):

Requests are processed asynchronously that is why sometimes it matched with counter 4 and activity gets finished.

Comment: yes, you're right, I'll try some modifications and let you know, thanks for the response.